# Migrating to react-router v4 - Route with children which requires router props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-router-v4

Can I get some advice on how to use my `AppMain` component which uses props passed down from `react-router` to get the data.

Here is what I have changed so far

v3:

```
<Router history={browserHistory} >
  <Route component={AppMain} exact path="/" >
    <IndexRoute name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Route name="Site Details" path="/details" component={SiteDetails} />
    <Route name="Home" component={Home} path="*" />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

v4

```
  <Router>
        <div>
          {/*<AppMain>*/}
          <Route component={AppMain} >
            <main>
              <Grid fluid className={classnames('app-content', { 'expanded': !this.state.mobileView && this.state.open })}>
                <Switch>
                  <Route name="Home" exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route name="Site Details" exact path="/details" component={SiteDetails} />
                </Switch>
              </Grid>
            </main>
          </Route>
          {/*</AppMain>*/}
        </div>
  </Router>
```

As you can see, I have attempted multiple methods of showing `AppMain` and `Home`/`SiteDetails` at the same time. This method gives me this warning which shows `AppMain` but none of its children:

`You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored`

The other method of using `<AppMain>` doesn't pass the `props.location.state...` which I am trying to convert my `AppMain` code to here:

v3

```
if (props.params.division !== undefined) {
  this.getDivision(props.params.division);
} else {
  this.getDivisions();
}
```

v4

```
if (props.location.state !== undefined) {
  if (props.location.state.division !== undefined) {
    this.getDivision(props.location.state.division.code);
  } else {
    this.getDivisions();
  }
} else {
  this.getDivisions();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was add a `Route` to `AppMain` outside the `Switch` with no path.

Here is my fix:

```
  <Router>
        <div>
          <Route component={AppMain} />
            <main>
              <Grid fluid className={classnames('app-content', { 'expanded': !this.state.mobileView && this.state.open })}>
                <Switch>
                  <Route name="Site Details" exact path="/details" component={SiteDetails} />
                  <Route name="Home" component={Home} />
                </Switch>
              </Grid>
            </main>
        </div>
  </Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

What if:

React Router v4:

```
     <Router>
        <div>
          <AppMain>
            <main>
              <Grid fluid className={classnames('app-content', { 'expanded': !this.state.mobileView && this.state.open })}>
                <Switch>
                  <Route name="Home" exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route name="Site Details" exact path="/details" component={SiteDetails} />
                </Switch>
              </Grid>
            </main>
          </AppMain>
        </div>
     </Router>
```

If you need location props in your `AppMain`, just wrap it with `withRouter` component: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep it on hand for another time. Turns out all I needed to do was put the `AppMain` component outside the switch